# input "value" is changing the output

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Pick 2 dates, calculate the total day difference between 2 dates and append it in #finaldays however somethig happens:

As I set value to input:

```
<input id="from" value="justAvalue" />
```

I get some unexpected result(negative num appears as you select later dan 14th),
 see(problem): http://jsfiddle.net/9EZXx/5/

If I just remove the value:

```
<input id="from" />
```

I just get the expected result, see: http://jsfiddle.net/f2hL6/1/

How does value of input change the situation?

"result must be: select date1 and as date2 selected output the result"

Comment: What is your problem.?

Comment: which browser you check. i checked in chrome its fine. and explain your problem in proper way.

Comment: when select second date with double click, a problem occurs but I m not sure it is his problem

Comment: as I use placeholder according to answer if @alphan it just works as it supposed to be..
"value" causes that.

Comment: It's possible that assigning a value (string) to an `<input>`, it changes automatically to an `<input type="text">`, then it tries to compare strings instead of date-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using placeholder instead of value

```
<input id="from" placeholder="aa" />
<input id="to" placeholder="aa" />
<div id="finalDays"></div>
```

Comment: You got it! But do you know why "value" changes it?

Comment: I don't know, it is really weird =)